# Silverlight CategoryAxis X widht stretch horizontally with scrollView

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, charts, windows-phone

I have Working Column Series.

I have around 50+ multiple column series to display, when there are more number of bars it shrinks the bar width and adjusts to chart width.

So i want to add a scroll only to Category Axis X and scroll horizontally with fixing the width of bars, if its more number of series the X axis should stretch horizontally.

here is the screen shot:

[image]

In the screen shot you can see that the 3rd series is cutting, and its not scrolling.

This is what i have tried:

```
<charting:Chart Name="barChart"
                                Style="{StaticResource PhoneChartStyle}"
                                Template="{StaticResource BarChartTemplate}">
                    <charting:Chart.Axes>
                        <charting:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="True" Title="Scores" Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" Maximum="50" Interval="10"/>
                        <charting:CategoryAxis HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                               Title="Fruits" 
                                               Width="1000"
                                               Orientation="X" 
                                               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        </charting:CategoryAxis>
                    </charting:Chart.Axes>
                    <charting:Chart.Series>
                        <charting:ColumnSeries 
                                    Title="Apple"
                                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                                    AnimationSequence="Simultaneous">
                            </charting:ColumnSeries>
                            <charting:ColumnSeries                 
                                    Title="Oranges"
                                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                                    AnimationSequence="Simultaneous">
                            </charting:ColumnSeries>
                            <charting:ColumnSeries                 
                                    Title="Guava"
                                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                                    AnimationSequence="Simultaneous">
                            </charting:ColumnSeries>
                    </charting:Chart.Series>
                </charting:Chart>*
```

Comment: Are you set barChart ItemSource dynamically or 50 constant series in you chart ???

Comment: @Jaihind its dynamic, it might contain 50 or 100 or some value

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and this trick solves the problem. May this will also help you.

```
<ScrollViewer Width="480" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,10">
<charting:Chart Name="barChart"
                                Style="{StaticResource PhoneChartStyle}"
                                Template="{StaticResource BarChartTemplate}" Width="460">
                    <charting:Chart.Axes>
                        <charting:LinearAxis ShowGridLines="True" Title="Scores" Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" Maximum="50" Interval="10"/>
                        <charting:CategoryAxis HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                               Title="Fruits" 
                                               Width="1000"
                                               Orientation="X" 
                                               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        </charting:CategoryAxis>
                    </charting:Chart.Axes>
                    <charting:Chart.Series>
                        <charting:ColumnSeries 
                                    Title="Apple"
                                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                                    AnimationSequence="Simultaneous">
                            </charting:ColumnSeries>
                            <charting:ColumnSeries                 
                                    Title="Oranges"
                                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                                    AnimationSequence="Simultaneous">
                            </charting:ColumnSeries>
                            <charting:ColumnSeries                 
                                    Title="Guava"
                                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}"
                                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                                    AnimationSequence="Simultaneous">
                            </charting:ColumnSeries>
                    </charting:Chart.Series>
                </charting:Chart>
</ScrollViewer>
```

//code behind where you set ItemSource of barChart
//I assume your itemSource should be a List collection = new List();
//barChart.ItemSource = collection ;

```
if (collection .Count() > 2)
{
   barChart.Width = barChart.Width + (collection .Count() * 80);
}
```

Comment: This will scroll the entire chart right ? but i want to scroll only the X series

Comment: @Goofy yes, i agree with you. I had same kind of problem, at last i went with this solution.

Comment: I had tried this before,anyways what does do ? barChart.Width = barChart.Width + (collection .Count() * 80); and do we need to set static value of barchart Width="460" ?

Comment: Yes it is necessary to keep the width of barchart as 460(fit to screen) just to make scroll work. And barChart.Width + (collection .Count() * 80); increases the width by 80 pixels per item in the collection when the condition is met. Do remember so set width of the scrollviewer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49664/discussion-between-goofy-and-jaihind)

Comment: @Goofy Sorry i am leaving now, sure will continue tomorrow on same.